# Factorials of primes decomposition

Tags: code-golf, number, primes, rational-numbers, factorial

You have to decompose a positive integer/fraction as a product of powers of factorials of prime numbers.

For example

> `22 = (11!)^1 × (7!)^(−1) × (5!)^(−1) × (3!)^(−1) × (2!)^1`

> `10/9 = (5!)^1 × (3!)^(−3) × (2!)^1`

Use this special notation: `prime number#power`
to denote each term, e.g. `(11!)^4` is denoted as `11#4`.

Output the non-zero terms only, with space separation.

The above examples hence become:

> `22 = 11#1 7#-1 5#-1 3#-1 2#1`

> `10/9 = 5#1 3#-3 2#1`

### Input & Output

- You are given a positive number `N`, that can be either an integer or a fraction of the form `numerator/denominator`
- The ordered list of the non-zero terms of the decomposition of `N`, denoted using the special notation
- You are allowed to output the terms as a list/array (containing strings with the special notation `#`)
- You are allowed to output the terms in any order
- Duplicate prime numbers are allowed
- You are not allowed to use terms that have to the power of `0`

### Test cases

```
6 -> 3#1
5040 -> 7#1
22 -> 11#1 7#-1 5#-1 3#-1 2#1
1/24 -> 3#-1 2#-2
720/121 -> 11#-2 7#2 5#3 3#3
```

This is code-golf, shortest code wins!

Credits to [this puzzle](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/factorials-of-primes-decomposition)

Comment: Ah ok, the `#` notation is mandatory, but the join by spaces is optional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134238/discussion-between-dialfrost-and-kevin-cruijssen).

Comment: I’d suggest standard site rules for the output.

Comment: May I include terms where power is 0? For example, `7 -> 7#1, 5#-1, 3#-1, 2#0`?

Comment: @tsh "_Output the non-zero terms only_" (not sure why though).

Comment: are we supposed to deal with `N=1` ?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen but then it would be confused if `7 -> 7#1, 5#-1, 3#-1, 2#1 2#-1` is allowed or not…

Comment: @tsh That one is allowed indeed. Which is why I said "_not sure why though_". Excluding `0` doesn't add much to the challenge, except that `1` (and perhaps `1/1`) are edge cases and should return `p#x p#-x` (e.g. `2#1 2#-1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
þ>LD(«ZÅPâæ¦.Δε`!sm}PI.EQ}í'#ý
```

Outputs as a list of strings. Can output with duplicated prime numbers as allowed in the rules (e.g. `3/4` results in `["3#1","2#-1","2#-2"]` instead of `[3#1","2#-3"]`).
Brute-force approach, so very slow and times out for most test cases.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9vc2FiaWX//8O@PkxEKMKrWsOFUMOiw6bCpi7OlM61YCFzbX1QSS5FUX3DrScjw73//zM) or [verify some test cases using values below `3` by replacing the `þ>`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhlf@NfVw0Dq2OOtwacHjR4WWHlumdm3Jua4JicW5twKF1eq6BtYfXqisf3vtf53@0oY6RjrGOiY6ZjoWOpY6Sob6REog0BpJGYNJQ3wRIGoNJQ30zMGkJJo1MlGIB).

**Explanation:**

```python
þ         # Keep the digits of the (implicit) input, potentially removing the "/"
          # for fractions
 >        # Increase it by 1 (for edge case input=1 or 1/1)
  LD(«    # Convert it into a [value,-value]-ranged list without 0:
  L       #  Pop the copy and push a list in the range [1,value]
   D      #  Duplicate this list
    (     #  Negate each value
     «    #  Merge the two lists together
  Z       # Push the maximum (without popping), which is the value again
   ÅP     # Pop and push a list of primes <= this value
      â   # Cartesian power to create all possible pairs of the two lists
       æ  # Get the powerset of this list of pairs
        ¦ # Remove the leading empty list (for edge case input=1 or 1/1 again,
          # because the product of an empty list is 1)
.Δ        # Find the first result which is truthy for:
  ε       #  Map the list of pairs to:
   `      #   Pop and push the values in the pair separated to the stack
    !     #   Take the factorial on the second
     s    #   Swap so the other is at the top
      m   #   Exponent the two together
  }P      #  After the map: take the product of the values
    I     #  Push the input
     .E   #  Evaluate it as Elixir code, which calculates the value for factorial
          #  inputs and will keep integer inputs unchanged
       Q  #  Check if they're the same
 }í       # After we've found our result: reverse each inner pair
   '#ý   '# Join each inner pair with "#"-delimiter
          # (after which the list is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>133</strike> 130 bytes

```python
import math
g=lambda i,k=1,n=1,j=2:i%j%i and g(i,k,n,j+1)or(i+k<3)*" "or"%s#%s "%(j,n)*(i>1)+g(k*math.factorial(j-1),i//j or 1,-n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFhb4MgEIa/91fcaEyA0lpssw9u9o8YP9iVWqyCAZZ0v94dumZbs12C5PB571644SNcrNmNo@4H6wL0dbgsmqKr@@OpBi2uhRQGV1tkuU7aRENtTtBQ/COMaFeSWUf16vq6Y5wAsY4kfpl4IAlthWGc6oNkq4Zeeay8OddvwTpdd7RdSyZ0mrZgHUixNmwMygcPBZSlFM@VKOPKMvxIke3jlm2F3FfV4oySANrApMgXgOFUlDaUBzblg9MmUJKSTWu1oX09UB@cCIwJRO@MPaHowZl/7yliExE7NS62QtHGD53GmkDY3DOGPiPwncY4ClXEfmhANO6uWpKvmj@UCg6wzaMNXjy4ODLO1S9edV5NbJr@Ba9nWt2Gf6/EQ7mt0pR2ymB6kNMsQymraQazO3Q1PctTEUvl8zPGE4Epe1E3vAuObvwE)

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to loopy walt</sup>

<sup>-5 more bytes if using python 3.8, as pointed out by ovs</sup>

Returns a whitespace separated string.

Uses a recursive algorithm: `i` is the numerator and `k` is the denominator. If `n` is -1, the roles are reversed. `j` is a potential divisor of `i`; `j` is incremented until it divides `i`. After this, we add `j#n` to the output and the function is called again with the roles reversed (`n` is negated). More precisely for inputs `i`, `k` we recurse with `i=k*fact(j-1),k=i//j`. This halts, because every step we are removing one "instance" of the prime number `j`, and only possibly adding smaller primes.

Just for fun, here are some shorter programs using looser IO rules:

[106 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZDBboMwDIbvPEUukwh1B6Hd2lF5L4I4ZCVRgyBBiXfY07MEtGmrpvmS385n/3HmD7o5e1gWM83OE5sk3TKNo5zeeskMWBQwYN20omsb8yo6afvcPAwsnkznEYBhJ7jz7QC228VKWUbFo0qjHrW8kvNGjvmwFxz2lvNfVqQCBYasFVDDAY7wBM9wgjO8gKi6TDvPiBnLVq7JWAyvUoPOia/p7I2lnCCWvwquj8CdPRVFvd2n7mojoxKrSj4q@cQpm0sKo1lArJqA4jKjulydJWPf1U9AIYomWRZ45zjzb06NQa1QWf5DBdyeJUNQ8X@2Pf5epKDlEw): Integer input only, returns flat list

Comment: It's actually cheaper to use `math.factorial`.

Comment: If you require *3.8+* `math.perm` is shorter than `math.factorial`

Comment: [125 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZFvb8IgEMbf@ykYpgkgWqlmWbrVL9L0RZ1YqS0QYIn79N1BZ/Yn2yWUHP09dw@cfQ8Xo3dP1k2TGq1xAY1tuCy6amjH46lFil8rwTWsvipKlfWZQq0@oY7AH655vxLUOKJW15cdZRhh43Dml5lHOCM915QRdRB01ZEri5U3VrqR9GtBucrzHhmHBF9rOgXpg0cVqmvBHxtex1UU8BG82Met2HKxb5rFGSQBKY2SolwgCCejtCMs0JRbp3QgOMeb3ihNxtYSHxwPlHJA74w5gSiZOrevwTjVDsS/jQSwRMROnYutQLTxdlBQE2E694yhzgB8pTGOXFaxHxjgnburlviz5jelRAe0LaMNVv1ycaSMyR@8HLxMbJ7/Ba9nWt7sv1diod42eU4GqSE9iDTGUIsmzWB2B67SszxUsVQ5P2M84ZDSZ3mDu8Dopg8) from @ovs 's comment

Answer (score 2):

## Excel (Insider Beta), 350 bytes

```
=LET(e,IFERROR(FIND("/",A1),0),n,ROW(1:99),m,COLUMN(A:CU),p,SORT(FILTER(n,MMULT(1*(MOD(n,m)=0),n^0)=2),,-1),f,LAMBDA(d,LET(c,MMULT((MOD(d,p^m)=0)*1,n^0),h,LAMBDA(x,y,SUM(INT(x/y^n))),z,TRANSPOSE(MINVERSE(MAKEARRAY(25,25,LAMBDA(x,y,h(INDEX(p,x),INDEX(p,y)))))),MMULT(z,c))),r,IF(e,f(LEFT(A1,e-1))-f(MID(A1,e+1,99)),f(A1)),CONCAT(IF(r,p&"#"&r&" ","")))
```

Uses `MAKEARRAY` and `LAMBDA` which are not widely available yet. Prime factors are not duplicated.  Works for all numbers \$ <= 2^{20} \$ whose prime factors are all \$<100\$.

### Explanation

`=LET(e,IFERROR(FIND("/",A1),0),` Finds position of "/"; return 0 if not found

`n,ROW(1:99),` vertical array of 1..99

`m,COLUMN(A:CU),` horizontal array of 1..99

`p,SORT(FILTER(n,MMULT(1*(MOD(n,m)=0),n^0)=2),,-1),` reverse sort of all primes \$<100\$.

`f,LAMBDA(d,` `f` is the function that returns the array of prime factorials for an integer \$>1\$.

`LET(c,MMULT((MOD(d,p^m)=0)*1,n^0),` the vertical array of the number of times each prime divides \$d\$.

`h,LAMBDA(x,y,SUM(INT(x/y^n))),` function that returns the number of times \$y\$ divides \$x!\$.

`MAKEARRAY(25,25,LAMBDA(x,y,h(INDEX(p,x),INDEX(p,y))))` an array indicating how many times each prime divides the factorial of each prime

`z,TRANSPOSE(MINVERSE(~)),` the inverse of the prime matrix, note: I had to use `TRANSPOSE` instead of reversing x & y because of some weird precision errors.

`MMULT(z,c))),` matrix multiply z and c, this transforms the number of times each prime divides d to the powers of prime factorials

`r,IF(e,f(LEFT(A1,e-1))-f(MID(A1,e+1,99)),f(A1)),` if \$e>0\$ then \$r=f(num.)-f(denom.)\$ else \$r=f(n)\$.

`CONCAT(IF(r,p&"#"&r&" ","")))` if an element in \$r>0\$ then return \$p\$#\$r\$ and then concatenate.

Comment: Not sure if it'll help here, but you should take a look at the [new insider preview functions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-new-text-and-array-functions/ba-p/3186066) - they are certain to help with golfing

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 222 bytes

```javascript
x=>([n,d=1]=x.split('/'),(f=r=>r<2?'':(((i=y=>y<2||r%y&&i(~-y))(~-r)?v=(q=s=>s%r?0n:-~q(s/r))(n,w=q(d)):v=w=0n)-w?' '+r+'#'+(v-w):'')+f(~-r,n*=(F=n=>n?n*F(~-n):1n)(r)**w,d*=F(r)**v))((n=(z=BigInt)(n))>(d=z(d))?n:d).trim())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRNb@IwFLzzK15VFdshUKj2BDhIe6i0f2AvVVUh7FDvpk5wTIAC/evss00I9GOl3QOx8/w8M56M@TWtpuXMqMJ2dS7kYZbr0sJiwQ9rntAHHQs@eOTrXllkylJyS1hMU254YsZ3E0KGlFLFNzzZjO92O3OzabcVfetuGMOnYZOK0wUveVLemElfD7tvC1reGlzV8YovqGBsWPEV72vWXU0IkI7pkGvSoVV3xYaEsE7qcGIdcXrPNU/0REf3WNJsONCMGhZFq1hE/N5PKwSmmtNX/l3Nf2iLNIwlVPBXxzTRQ8F61qgXythh1GqFs75M108aOHzrYyld6plVuYZ0OrO5UdMMIVrbFkAmLZgK@wZ6hK9pboC62rGE45iDGzsdhuvgmiMOlWs20i6NxsqotT/jUOVTgWokLQKFSoEWDmZwRAjb0mlWygtOgZx3yCVgDAUONWUAuHHrHPqh9hHm@G7NUgY9NaxC2D7CKq/BzwKyMyrPZC/L55ScnIE8JTGoGIgqcdI4phg7unvaRFzlH4lqe97xnFwLNCc3K2lUusFggYihtGbemOre4IoDysDK1vvidGTT0iIYqllqIVOlpRj5Ra80xMPmv1GAB6wvARAWvN0eHQ6dpSwQCfvrvmt36tDhVciil0k9t8@oBT8gg@MigH02@Qr6ows8FAYIGKLsdj/0H9lli1wXT5ctg8cLztCAbsNuB1dN4Axzhfr87TbmxkDC6wpjX0lrLCvMB6KkCR1gCDH@TSgcZRR5xfU@iYE8tetP27tN/74Vfo5NewdFIDspxCz/LXX6eFO1S52/9Th3udu2aj8Xi5@Ya44jboYOaG/mOSbGyzf5hSZyg7P6/v9UXNzuQbjdpw7xpU6NMvFvGZ/Cawr2@HvlvqsI0@DUu4PgNn9ZPjvQWXl/@AM)

`.trim()` could be removed (-7 bytes) if you were willing to tolerate an extraneous space at the start of the output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>94</s> 89 bytes

```
≔Ｉ…⪪⁺Ｓ/1¦/²θ≔Πθη≔²ζＷ⊖η¿﹪ηζ≦⊕ζ≧÷ζηＷ⊖ζ¿∨¬⬤…²ζ﹪ζκΠ﹪θζ≦⊖ζ¿¬Σ﹪θζ≧÷ζθ«Ｉζ#⌕﹪θζ⁰1→ＵＭθ⎇﹪κζ×κΠ…·¹ζκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJLasMwEF03pxDuZgQuib0pNKvgUMgibUh6AWFPLRFZ8kd2SUrP7sqS3SSQbmRm9H4zcspZnWom@37VNCJXkLDGQHJKJSZcl3AopTCwk20DG1W25mBqoXKgIQnmUeA@wxlTe1R0ORtVdrXO2tRAZdv80o5DcrbVFxcSCawxrbFAZTADTikRnwS2lic18AFIyZaVI3Oj/rBOg6Bs8HK/Fzk3FmTWohMZWoj3veN0Hp3ea3jTBlZSwp6pHH24kIwJrMCRDlNNo4z9yiW7yXal7udz2QaPweDQFv9z7@WuJoXv2cPObtv4N7HM5dQIHoNL8SpUduMQksU1NnLYre4QXpyfK1mZ6KJglmo5H1grVp8mlaNX@RAFNkMxrcA@gv0RRId@YZEfxy1qOfvp@@d4MY/iqH/q5C8) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs each prime factorial once per power. Explanation:

```
≔Ｉ…⪪⁺Ｓ/1¦/²θ
```

Append "/1" to the input in case it's a single integer, then split it on "/" and take the first two values.

```
≔Πθη≔²ζＷ⊖η¿﹪ηζ≦⊕ζ≧÷ζη
```

Find the largest prime number dividing either the numerator or denominator.

```
Ｗ⊖ζ¿∨¬⬤…²ζ﹪ζκΠ﹪θζ≦⊖ζ
```

Loop though the prime numbers down to `2`, decrementing if the current number is not prime or does not divide either the numerator or denominator.

```
¿¬Σ﹪θζ≧÷ζθ«
```

If the current prime number divides both numerator and denominator, start reducing the fraction to its lowest terms, otherwise:

```
Ｉζ#⌕﹪θζ⁰1→
```

Print the current prime number with "#-1" if it's a factor of the denominator or "#1" if it's a factor of the numerator, leaving a space between prime factorials.

```
ＵＭθ⎇﹪κζ×κΠ…·¹ζκ
```

Multiply whichever isn't a factor by the factorial of the prime.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 120 bytes

```javascript
p=>q=>(o={},g=(v,t,i=2,h=j=>j?h(--j,g(j,-t)):i)=>{for(;v>1;)v%i?++i:delete o[i*!(o[h(i,v/=i)]=~~o[i]+t)]})(q,~g(p,1))||o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bczBCoJAEIDhe09Rh2Amx9KlCIzZHkQ8RK26izRmy140X93sGHX9@PndJVye1862Pr7LzUwlTy3rB2sQ7l9UMQTyZFlRzY61O9cQx44qcBR7xMwi676UDk5BpycMa3uOIpvdTGO8WUpuNyuQvAZLYccWCx7HGYvIY/FCeNBYQUsp4jDIdJX7UxqzbaSCEo4Isy@@8ZDsk3@u1D9NEdT@R4/qs1BzPr0B)

- [+13 bytes](https://tio.run/##bczBCoJAEIDhe09Rh2Amx8rFCIrZHqEHCA9lq84irumyl8hXNztGXT9@fnsN1z7vpPVx4@5mLHhsWT9Yn2/W5H5tGt@J6cHx80UlQyBPwooqtqztqYI4tlSCpdgjHgRZPwvXwTHo5IhhKacoksPd1MabubvIagHuUoFQ2LBgxsMwYRZ5zKY7PGgooaUEEcfcNb2rzbp2JRSwR5h09o27bbr950r90wRBpT@6V5@FmvLxDQ) if output as an array.

  - [+26 more bytes](https://tio.run/##bczRaoNAEIXh@z5FSgnM1NXGJSWQMJtH6AMEQWtWncU6RpclEOKrW0uvSnN3@Dj8rgjFWA7c@7iTs50rmnsyFzIfn86WPrGdH9iOIHS7q5ogKK@YtGrIkXHHBuLYqRqcij3inpHMrZIBDsGkBwxrPkYR78@2td6u5MSvzyCnBliFN2LMaJoWzCKP2VKHi5pq6FWKiMlX0cOVzDVxwl3@kuPvWOVzKd0orU1aqaGCHcLyf/qL75vt5pFr/UhTBL39pzv9k9DLff4G) to format the string with hash and spaces.
- [-9 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZctLCoMwEADQfU/RLgozNbYaLIIyehBxITZqgjiiIRs/V7fdFrcPnqlcNdeTHq0/8EcdDR0jZcC0bKIlcMIKTVJ0ZCgzeQe@b0QLRvgWMdFI2dLwBKnLwhTdXeeep5OP6pVVVy704wZcdKCFe5HGkvb9h6VnsdwQRhHiuvJR8zBzr549t9BAjHj5l3cQBSeU8kzRiWJ5nqEMEY8v) if we only accept integer inputs.

  - [-34 more bytes](https://tio.run/##XcpBCoMwEEDRfU@RTWEGE2qCRVBGzyKt0UmphhgCpfTs6aKb6vb974Y0bLfAPqrN830Mz3V5jK9sKU8ESUbSksnImRx1rp9BKScncFJFxIaRurddA7Sp0y2mM/dFwY0PvESYgWW6EKOM@MkWaiEEtuIX8WThWlblDow5HKY6QG3KPWij/yB/AQ) if output duplicate items

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 461 bytes:

```py
from itertools import*
import math
def s(n=1):
 while(n:=n+1):
  if all(n%i for i in range(2,n)):yield n
r=lambda x:pow(*x[0][:-1])*(not x[1:]or r(x[1:]))
F=math.factorial
def f(n):
 q,Q=[[[],2,s()]],[]
 while q:
  p,I,v=q.pop(0)
  for i in product(*[range(-I,I)]*len(p)):
   if all(i)and p and round(r([[a,z,c]for(a,c),z in zip(p,i)]),4)==round(n,4):return' '.join(f'{b}#{j}'for(_,b),j in zip(p,i))
  q+=[[p+[[F(P:=next(v)),P]],I,s(P)],[p,I+1,s(P)],[p,I,s(P)]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDNTsMwEITveYqVEOpuakoSyo8i5YrUWzlbFnKbhLpK167rQini2YvTAsrFnllZs/PZfYaV5bsn50@n1tsNmND4YG23A7Nx1oc0udyw0WGV1E0LO@QqpzKBj5XpGuSy4vHZg2lBdx3ytYHWejBgGLzmtwYLwUTlp2m6GjjxVac3i1rDoXT2A9ODzJQsb3JFKbINcJB5qWKAx7MiSp6rfv2k1ctgvdHduUiL3K/dipdKSqlEIXZISgmpfrvBtm/lxEy8V9uJsw4zioP/bs7ber8MmMpLy5uZmJFKu4bR0ZnoD8mQ5hoc9Ke3e67Ro5RaHMVSxTjUYkni2GcejUMnDCkSU6qqy2OOuvRN2HsewWiytoaxHX0tvq@@1t@jPuBVLEishwF90@04krmxlM84j9/cHAK@E4l5hJxF2DlF2Ig3zgfmItXJecMBW3yISX/6PptmA1sUA5PfFtOBfSyy27zIiU4/)

Basic brute force solution, but still runs quickly on the test cases.

Comment: Isn't `1 if not x[1:]else r(x[1:])` just `not x[1:]or r(x[1:])`? You can also remove the space at `return'` and merge the last three lines to `q+=[[p+[[F(P:=next(v)),P]],I,s(P)],[p,I+1,s(P)],[p,I,s(P)]]`.

Comment: Save one byte by defining your own factorial function rather than using `math.factorial` and then removing `import math`.